# Displaying multiple Point 3D s in Helix Tool Kit

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I need to display multiple 3d points in a Helix View Port.

```
private void DisplayPointCloud(double[] datapoints)
    {

                newTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;
                foreach (double Datapoint in datapoints)
                {

                    Point3D temp = new Point3D(Random(), Random(), Datapoint);

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        DataList.Add(temp);
                    });
                        
                }
       
        oldTime = newTime;
    }
```

I am displaying data in Helix Viewport in a separate thread. I need to show multiple datapoints in the UI without showing one by one which I'm doing right now. Main reason I need to do so is minimize the lag in UI Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HelixToolkit** have a good samples on [github](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/develop/Source/Examples).

Regarind points.. you can use **PointsVisual3D** in your view and bind your source collection of Point3D to property Points.

```
<h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="ViewPort3D" InfiniteSpin="True" ShowFrameRate="True">
            <h:DefaultLights />
            <h:PointsVisual3D Points="{Binding Points3DCollection}" Color="Red" Size="6" />
        </h:HelixViewport3D>
```

Even if you will decide to populate Points3DCollection from different non UI thread - it will not solve issue with UI Thread. The root cause - Helix alway will repaint this collection after change camera position. Repaint performs in UI thread.

For increase responsive for rest of controls on your form - you can try create new thread for you HelixViewPort3D (see [Dwayne Need article](https://dwayneneed.github.io/wpf/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.html)), but it will not significant increase speed of repaint your 3D scene.